# Custom field validation when registering. Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem when validating customer registration form. It's not working at all.
I want to validate my custom field added to reg form.
I will write steps which I've done and please tell me my problem.

1. I've added custom field in registration form. Which is placed in `/themes/THEME/authentication.tpl`

   ```
   <div class="required form-group">
           <label for="user_id_number">ID <sup>*</sup></label>

           <input type="text"  onkeyup="$('#user_id_number').val(this.value);" 
           class="is_required validate account_input form-control"  id="user_id_number" name="user_id_number" 
           value="{if isset($smarty.post.user_id_number)}{$smarty.post.user_id_number}{/if}" />
       </div>
   ```
2. Overridden `Address.php (AddresCore Class)` and added my field name to `$definition` array.

   ```
    class Address extends AddressCore {
             public $user_id_number;

           public static $definition = array(
      'table' => 'address',
     'primary' => 'id_address',
     'fields' => array(
     'id_customer' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
       'id_manufacturer' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
       'id_supplier' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
       'id_warehouse' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
       'id_country' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
       'id_state' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId'),
       'alias' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
       'company' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 64),
       'lastname' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
       'firstname' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
       'vat_number' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName'),
       'address1' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
       'address2' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'size' => 128),
       'postcode' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPostCode', 'size' => 12),
       'city' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isCityName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 64),
       'other' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMessage', 'size' => 300),
       'phone' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 32),
       'phone_mobile' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 32),
       'dni' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isDniLite', 'size' => 16),
       'deleted' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
       'date_add' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
       'date_upd' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),

       'user_id_number' =>     array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isValidIdNumber', 'required' => true), //My Custom Field
   ),
   );

    public function __construct(){
      // var_dump($user_id_number);
    }

    }
   ```
3. Overridden `Validation.php (ValidationCore Class)` and added my validation function.

   ```
     class Validate extends ValidateCore {



      public static function isValidIdNumber($user_id_number){
       var_dump($user_id_number);

        if( strlen($user_id_number) != 11){
           return false;
       }

      return false;
      }
    }
   ```
4. Added my custom field variable to `AuthController.php`
   [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsLEO.png)
   [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avMQN.png)
5. Added new field to `ps_customer` database table.

What I've I missed?

Comment: Please add your code for each of those points and add any related errors.

Comment: I've added codes and images, 
si vous pouvez aider moi, je vais reconnaissant, 

I'm sorry for my french knowladge, I am learning it now,